# RemoveEventListener doesn't work inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I try to make lazy loading for my products list using React and Redux. The problem is that I can't removeEventListener after all products are loaded.

`all_loaded` tells me if are products are loaded (true) or not (false).

So after the `all_loaded` changed to true, useEffect run code inside `else` but eventListener still exist after that.

```
const { all_loaded } = useAppSelector((state) => state.productsSlice);

  const bottomScrollDetection = () => {
    const position = window.scrollY;
    var limit = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;

    if (position === limit) {
      dispatch(fetchProducts(true));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts(false));
    if (!all_loaded) {
      document.addEventListener("scroll", bottomScrollDetection);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", bottomScrollDetection);
    }
  }, [all_loaded]);
```

Comment: Use the cleanup of useEffect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the next re-render, a new function will be affected to `bottomScrollDetection`, the `removeEventListener` call will not remove the initial listener.

You can use the cleanup function :

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!all_loaded) {
    dispatch(fetchProducts(false));

    document.addEventListener("scroll", bottomScrollDetection);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", bottomScrollDetection);
  }
}, [all_loaded]);
```